# Import large external MySQL XML dump into my own databases?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xsd

We need to import a MySQL dump from another website to ours.  We've been trying SimpleXML, XML DOM etc, but the file is so huge it's crashing our server.  We looked into BigDump, but that doesn't handle the XML import.  Every tag in our XML file is called <field name="something"> In <table_something> tags, which I haven't seen before - usually it's descriptive custom tags. This is probably because I haven't done much database importing before now,

What we would like is some way to make our PHP import this huge file.  It needs to be freshly updated every night so I'm thinking of dropping the tables and importing fresh unless there's a way to search for differences but I wouldn't know how.

Can anyone help with this?  What would be the standard procedure for achieving these results?

Answer (score 0):

Moving a database is usually done outside of PHP, via command line script:

1. Dump db to a file
2. tar the file
3. FTP to new server

Then on the new server

1. untar the file
2. Import to mysql

Do you have shell access?

If you have to do it via PHP, you'll need to split up the dump into lots of tiny files and import them one at a time. Depending on the size of your database, this could take a really long time.

When doing the dump, minimize the file size by not using XML, stripping comments, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an external site's "feed".  It is a property rental site of which we're affiliates with thousands of properties so we don't control the size or style of the dump.  Also, we don't have shell access to this host, and have to keep our database up to date from this file.

Your second idea of splitting the dump would be good, but would require extra space and time on our server, which isn't a good idea.  Also, we don't know if this database is updated and dumped to XML every day, which would mean about a Gig of transfer every time.

We'll look around, thanks for taking time :)